# Jinja2 if value less than zero

Tags: latex, jinja2

I am using Python and Jinja2 to generate a LaTeX table.  The following code produces the bottom row of the table:

```
<snip>
    \hline
    \BLOCK{for col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 in shareCompSum}
    \VAR{col1} & \VAR{col2} & \VAR{col3}\euro & \VAR{col4}\euro & \VAR{col5}\euro & \VAR{col6}\euro \\
    \BLOCK{endfor}
    \hline
<snip>
```

The corresponding LaTeX-output is as follows:

```
\hline
Profit/Loss &  & -174.040\euro & -9.040\euro & -723.20\euro & -733.28\euro \\
\hline
```

For columns 3 to 6, I would like the text color to be changed to red if the value of variable col3 is negative, and normal black if positive.

I am trying to write a statement along the following lines:

```
{% if col3 < 0 %} \textcolor{red}{\VAR{col3}\euro}
{% else %} \VAR{col3}\euro {% endif %}
```

It seems that Jinja does evaluate the if condition, but as a string-test rather than on numbers.

How can I perform the evaluation of float/numbers in Jinja?

Comment: Simply defining the variable col3 as a float does the trick: {% if col3|float < 0.0 %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable col3 appears as a string.  You can set it to float via the following syntax:

```
{% if col3|float < 0.0 %} \textcolor{red}{\VAR{col3}\euro}
{% else %} \VAR{col3}\euro {% endif %}
```

The above Jinja code will typeset the variable col3 in red if negative, and black when larger than or equal to zero